# Find all Core Data entries (using NSDate) that occurred on a weekend

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsdate

I have a Core Data managed class of phone calls (Entity name: **phoneCall**) with an NSDate attribute (attribute name: **callTime**). How do I efficiently query or filter all phone calls that were made on the weekend (Saturday and Sunday) using Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way would be to add a "dateIsWeekend" flag or a weekday value to your phone call records and save it up-front. Then filter based on that.

That spends some extra time up-front setting up your data, but makes queries very fast.

Another option would be to add a computed property to your subclass of NSManagedObject that tells you if a date is on a weekend. That method should use a static NSCalendar object and NSDateComponents object to figure it out so you're not constantly creating objects when you do a query. Then you could write your query based on that computed property.